# Schema: two-way relationships? which table/entity should own 'preference'?

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I'm not sure how to ask this question, so I'll be as clear as I can with an example.

In an app like facebook, a Profile can have multiple ProfilePictures.  At any given time, one of these is the "selected" ProfilePicture (assuming a ProfilePicture has been uploaded).

Instinctively, I would model this like:

```
Table: Profile
--------------
ProfileID
SelectedProfilePictureId //fk to ProfilePicture
Name, Age, Etc

Table: ProfilePicture
---------------------
ProfilePictureId
ProfileId //fk to Profile, indicating which Profile this picture belongs to
Url, DateTaken, Etc
```

At this point, these tables point to each other and it just seems "wrong" to me.  It makes it easy to query for Profiles without SelectedProfilePictures or to get a Profile's SelectedPicture, but inserts and updates are a little wonky.

Is this bad form?  Should the Profile table be completely independant of the ProfilePicture table?  Is there a "correct" way to model this according to database design theory, or is it up to the descretion of the programmer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct, this is called a circular reference and you actually cannot make the database do it.

One simple solution is a "preferred" flag on the child table of pictures.  But you have a biz logic issue here: only one row for a given person can be preferred.  So when anybody marks a new one as preferred, you must clear any others.

A safer solution is to add a third table "preferredPictures" with foreign keys to Profiles and ProfilePictures.  Make it unique on profileId, so it can never have more than one entry.  This forces a deletion of a prior entry before insertion of a new one.  Or of course you can just do an update of an existing.

**EDIT:** in response to comment.

1) No circular reference because Profiles is parent of both child tables, it does not loop around to Profiles

```
Profiles
   |  |
   |  +-----> PreferredPicture
   |  +----->
   |  |
  \|/ |
ProfilePictures
```

2) Primary key of Preferred Picture is ProfileId, it is technically a 1:1 child table of Profiles.

Comment: I managed to make the circular references work in Sql Server 2008 R2 but it was a little hack-y (I couldn't create a new ProfilePicture and set the SelectedProfileId field of Profile during the same transaction, for instance).

Comment: So basically, you're saying the third table breaks the circular reference because the Profile table no longer references the ProfilePicture table?  And the PreferredPictures table would have a one-to-one relationship with each the Profiles and the ProfilePictures tables?  What would the primary key of the PreferredPictures table be? (sorry for so many questions!)

Comment: That makes sense... thanks for the info and the ascii art!  I'll upvote your answer as soon as I manage to get 15 "reputation" on this site.

Comment: @smalltown happy to help.  The fifteen will come before you know it.

Answer (score 1):

why would you need to keep the ProfileID in the ProfilePicture Table ??

if you need this you may need a 3rd Table in which you build the association:

ProfileID<->ProfilePictureID

Comment: So the ProfilePicture table doesn't need to know about the Profile table?  It would just describe an image, and a third table would relate Profiles to ProfilePictures?  Would that third table also be able to store which ProfilePicture is "selected", or would that be in another table?

Comment: You may have a Picturestable in thich the ProfileID stored, so you will be able to select all pictures belonging to profile X, as each pivture belongs to only one profile. in addition you have to know which picture is the selected profilepicture, you can make this either by creating a boolean IsSelectedProfilePicture-Column where you set to true only the one selected, or better you make a 3rd table in which you keep only the reference to profile and to picture.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with kind of "circular reference" on other projects before.

if Profile.SelectedProfilePictureId is Nullable and ProfilePicture.ProfileId is Mandatory this is fine. only if you make both fk mandatory you get a real circular reference which is not possible.